# Microsoft Edge add http request header on virtual box

Tags: http, web, proxy, httpwebrequest, microsoft-edge

I have a mac, I need to test my website on Microsoft Edge in Windows using a virtual box. I want to add some http request headers to the call. However, I only found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/mobile/mcsf/custom-http-headers-for-internet-explorer which is for the phone. I didn't find anything for desktop. Since it is on virtual box, I doubt apps like Charles would work either.

Comment: Why do you want to change Edge to test your website? It sounds like an X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @shaochuancs I need to test my website on different browsers because of some features on my website works differently on different browsers.

Comment: Then I think you can add the request header in your javascript code, no need to change Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at fiddler from Telerik.

It's a free web debugging proxy. With it you can intercept and modify pretty much everything that flows in and out of your browser.

[Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

From the menu choose Customize Rules. Adding a request header would require something like this to be added. The sample file is well documented.

```
oSession.oRequest["someHeaderToSend"] = "someValue";
```